# P&T Field pack within Safecracker

Tags: safecracker, fieldtype

Having a few problems with the P&T field pack working within safecracker.

I am trying to get a checkbox field working...

If I use the short field name tag i.e. `{field:mycheckboxes}` it works, it submits the correct checked boxes, and it remains checked if other elements of the form fail validation.

However, I want to specifically target the options in order to apply styling, but any combination I've used other than the short name, all fails to submit the data.

I've tried Low options, like so

```
{exp:low_options:walk_features_new}                           
{options}                                     
  <label class="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" name="walk_features_new[]" value="{walk_features_new:value}"/>
    {option:label}
  </label>
{/options}
{/exp:low_options:walk_features_new}
```

It all outputs correctly into the form, but nothing gets submitted.

Answer (score 1):

This is rather a HTML issue. "Look at the source Luke".

Use Chrome Devtools or Firebug to see how the basic {field:fieldname} field is rendered. Target your options from there. And even if you need and use an addon, look at the docs https://github.com/lodewijk/low_options. from what i read there it is {option:value}, not {fieldname:value}